# ERRO NO doInBackground

Tags: android

Esta função esta-me a dar  seguinte erro :

```
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... args0) {
                updateJSONdata();
                return null;

            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema, inclua o código da função `updateJSONdata();`. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que dentro de `updateJSONdata()` você esteja chamando uma `Toast`. Isso não é permitido porque a `Toast` só pode ser chamada no thread principal, que é responsável por atualizações da tela, enquanto que o método `doInBackground()` executa em um thread secundário, que não tem permissão para atualizar a tela.

Isso também pode acontecer se você estiver instanciando um `Handler` dentro de `updateJSONdata()`. O `Handler` é capaz de executar código no thread principal e portanto chamar a `Toast`. Se for esse o caso, uma maneira de corrigir o erro seria instanciar o `Handler` passando `Looper.getMainLooper()`, isto é:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Porém uma vez que você está usando `AsyncTask`, você não deveria instanciar `Handler` e sim executar instruções no thread principal usando a API de `AsyncTask`, isto é, sobrescrevendo e chamando métodos que a própria `AsyncTask` oferece para atualizar a tela durante ou após a execução de `doInBackground()`.

Esses métodos são:

- `publishProgress()` para atualizar a tela durante a execução de `doInBackground()` (no caso de `publishProgress()` você chama via `publishProgress()` mas o método a ser sobrescrito é `onProgressUpdate()`);
- `onPostExecute(result)` ou `onCancelled(result)` após a execução de `doInBackground()`. Ao contrário deste último, que executa em um thread separado, esses métodos que citei executam no thread principal (fazendo uso de um `Handler` internamente) e são os métodos apropriados para você sobrescrever e atualizar a tela.

Espero que tenha ficado claro, qualquer dúvida é só comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a implementação da sua função `updateJSONdata();`  para facilitar a ajuda.

A princípio, dentro de threads que não sejam runOnUiThread você não deve manipular views da thread principal (Activity)